# There is time-wave?

Tags: waves, spacetime, terminology

I was thinking that for the wave equation of a wave $u(x,t)$ and $c>0$:

$${\partial^2 u\over \partial t^2}=c^2{\partial^2 u\over\partial x^2}$$

besides the solution $$u(x+ct)+u(x-ct),$$ one can divide by $c^2$ and get the equation

$${1\over c^2}{\partial^2 u\over \partial t^2}={\partial^2 u\over\partial x^2} $$

and solutions $$u(t+{x\over c})+u(t-{x\over c}),$$ so maybe it can be thought that there is *time-wave* besides *spatial-wave*. In [Math Stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632017/) I gave the solution of a problem I had and came with the solution like this *time-wave*.

Comment: Hi Daniel Muñoz. Welcome to Phys.SE. That seems to be non-standard terminology.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks. What is the non-standard terminology?

Comment: the down voters should add comments

Answer (score 6):

The two are equivalent. The general solution can be written as

$$u(x,t) = f_1(x + ct) + f_2(x-ct)$$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are arbitrary functions. Now define $g_i(z) = f_i(cz)$; we have $f_i(x \pm ct) = g_i(x/c \pm t)$, so the very same solution can be written using the $g_i$ with $x/c \pm t$ as an argument. It's not a different kind of solution.

Comment: that's my point. If the wave equation is a good model, then can it be waves that travel in time, instead of space?

Comment: also... multiplying the argument by $c$ doesn't change to the previous result, because $(x/c)\pm t \neq t\pm (x/c)$ anf if we divide by $-c$ instead of $c$, then the argument is $-t\mp (x/c)$, so $z = \{-t + (x/c) , -t - (x/c)\}$

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to say that something travels in time instead of space, because the very concept of traveling requires a change with respect to time. Mathematically $u$ is just a function of two variables - "travel" is a physical interpretation we give to it.

Answer (score 1):

u(x,t) is a function of two variables: In one case it is viewed as a function of x with t held constant (a snap shot). In the other case it is viewed as a function of t with x held constant (a strip chart recording). The two cases are equivalent.